# Using Rpi pico and flex sensors to control a specific number of laptop inputs

Tags: embedded, sensors, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using three flex sensors and a raspberry pi pico board. What I am trying to do is take the inputs of sensors and process it through raspberry pi pico and then use the pico to do a certain task on my laptop. For example, when I bend the flex sensor, windows key function or any other key function should be happen on my laptop. My only doubt is whether it is possible to do this. If yes, how can I do it?

I've been searching on this topic for a while across different sources but cannot come to conclusion whether it is possible or not.

Comment: This is way too broad, you are asking how to design the entire system. That being said, I have done very similar projects in the past in a system where I had custom joystick -> MCU -> serial protocol -> Windows PC prog and then called functions like nowadays obsolete `keybd_event`/`mouse_event`. Running Windows mouse + keyboard from the custom joystick. So yes it is possible. How? Through engineering... good luck.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to make the Pico act as a 'USB HID' device, which would mean it could send 'key presses' to the host PC as if it were a USB keyboard. From a Web search I can't see if this capability exists in MicroPython for the Pico yet, but it does exist for some other MicroPython ports and it does exist in Adafruit's CircuitPython for the Pico. I suggest you ask on [MicroPython Discussions](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions) or look at CircuitPython. This question is too broad for Stack Overflow, but come back if you have a specific problem with your code.